# delete a specific string that starts with brackets [ and ends with brackets ]

Tags: regex, awk, sed

delete a line containing a specific string that starts with brackets [ and ends with brackets ] using sed

```
<p>["1284" align="" width="210" caption="blue sky"]<a href="http://www.domain.com/planes/2014/12/amazing-sky.html"><img class="alignleft size-full wp-image-1084" title="blue sky" src="http://www.domain.com/images/2014/12/amazing-sky.jpg" alt="blue sky" width="210" height="210" /></a></p>
<p>The <em>Blue Sky</em> airplane has the most powerful jet engine, <strong>Carter technicians</strong>, has proposed to expand the plane's wings.</p>
```

I have around twenty thousand articles that needs to be cleaned up in a directory.  I would like to remove
`["1084" align="" width="210" caption="blue sky"]` from the articles.  However, all of them are slightly different
except it starts with brackets [ and ends with brackets ]

Comment: thank you for the edit jurgemaister.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed -i.bak '/\[.*\]/d' file
```

to delete any line that `[...]` pattern.

`-i.bak` will save your original file with `.bak` extension.

Comment: What does the `/d` do? I thought that matched any digit.

Comment: That's \d which matches digit

Comment: @anubhava you are deleting those lines which has a string `[...]` in it but OP wants delete just string contain `[..]`. not the `<p>` in first line. So **Amit Anand**'s answer is correct

Comment: @KasiyA: That question was edited after I posted my answer. In case OP wants to just remove text between `[` and `]` then then OP should use: `sed -i.bak 's/\[.*\]//' file` Amit's answer is also correct in case there are several square brackets on same line.

Answer (score 2):

use
    `sed 's/\[[^]]*\]//g'` 

It will delete all words with [text]

Comment: Thank you.  I have selected anubhava's answer.  I also appreciate your input.

Comment: you are welcome.. I added incase you need to remove multiple square braces from a single line. :)

Comment: @AmitAnand - I didn't get a correct while i am giving this input      hello [welcome] to chennai [hai]
hello [how]
[is] this